# Add add-on to Azure Marketplace managed SendGrid subscription

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, azure-marketplace

I am currently attempting to add the [30 Days Additional Email Activity History](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/add-ons/30-days-additional-email-activity-history/) add-on to a sendgrid subscription that is managed from Azure Marketplace.

Is this possible?

I've tried clicking "Buy add-on" but end up on the "You don't have access to this page" page. I am the account admin, so would expect to have access.

I've also tried looking for the add-on inside Azure marketplace but can't locate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you buy SendGrid through the Azure Marketplace, you can only purchase what is included in the marketplace offering. To be able to purchase these add-ons, you need to create an account with SendGrid directly, which will also give you access to other features that aren’t available through the Azure Marketplace.

If you already have resources in your subscription you need to keep, I'd suggest reaching out to SendGrid support to help move things over to a direct SendGrid account.